# Google app engine cannot instantiate task queues more than the back end instances defined in backends.yaml in Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I have defined the backend configuration as follows.

```
 backends:
 - name: mybackend
   class: B8
   options: public, dynamic
   instances: 6
```

And Um creating more than 6 taskqueue instances and given the target to my backend.

```
 class TestHandlerTest(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         for x in range(0, 100):
             taskqueue.add(url='/testhandler/', method='GET',      params={'x': x},
                        target='mybackend')
         return Response()


 class TestHandler(RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         time.sleep(420)
         x = self.request.args.get('x')
         return Response()
```

In GAE taskqueue only getting queued with 6 taskqueue instances . It wont run up to 100. If we use front ends the taskqueue getting queued with 
all the taskqueues .

Why cannot we queued more than the tasks specified backend instance limit in google app engine? Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured 6 backend instances. You can add as many push tasks as you want to these backends. 
To do this you have to target the backend instance for each task you add. 
So target = '1.mybackend' for the first instance  and '2.mybackend' for the second backend inatnce.

Comment: well this is not what I have asked. Um using a one backend there um defining 6 instances and adding urls in to a taskqueu by a loop bigger than the number of instances from the backend. It only gets added  6 only others getting vanished

Comment: well thing is we are addressing backends dynamically so inside the loop the backends anyway getting instantiated :)

Comment: I'am not sure if you can address the backend queue without a instance. Because when you do not use a instance in your target it will add tasks to available instances. But after six no instance is "available" anymore. Does this make sense? So try it with target backend including the instance.

Comment: well it is possible in the loop it will create 6 instances its not necessary to create instances as 1.instance_name to ... n.instance_name

Comment: But maybe the problem is, that after adding six tasks no instances are available anymore. To add more tasks you have to use an instance.

Comment: Well but taskqueue must queued the tasks I mean all of them . The problem is why the other tasks does not get queued ? You have a point