# Google AppEngine task queue length

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a Google AppEngine back-end cron task that processes a large number of records. This handler reads records batch by batch in a loop and queues another back-end handler for each batch. I am using the default task queue for this. I have configured 6 back-end instances for this application. However only 6 tasks are queued and the rest is ignored. It seems that the number of tasks you can queue is equal to the number of back-ends and further task requests just get discarded. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Could you please share with us your configuration for the same?

Comment: No. I currently have a queue with 10,370 items in it waiting to be processed. Please show your code.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851975/google-app-engine-cannot-instantiate-task-queues-more-than-the-back-end-instance ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you enable https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests 
AsyncTasks use request to start new Tasks.